# How to logout after 60 seconds in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written jquery like below lines of code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 var t;
 window.onload=resetTimer;
 document.onkeypress = resetTimer;
 document.onmouseover = resetTimer;

 function logout() {
     var answer = confirm('You will be logged out after 60 Second');
     if (answer) {
         location.href = '../login/login.aspx'
     }
     else {
         window.onload = resetTimer;
     }
 }

 function resetTimer()
 {
 clearTimeout(t);
 t=setTimeout(logout,10000) //logs out in 10 min
 }

 </script>
```

Now I want that If user will not confirm after 60 second, it should be loggged out after 60 seconds i.e it should be redirected to login page. Please help
 me !!!

Comment: You can't interrupt a `confirm()` dialog. You should use an HTML dialog instead.

Comment: clear session for logout

Comment: I mean If user will not confirm after 60 second, it should be loggged out after 60 seconds.

Comment: `confirm()` will block the rest of the javascript from executing until true or false is returned. It's blocking the rest of the source code. As Barmer has pointed out, use HTML dialog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`confirm()` blocks all other Javascript, so you can't cancel it when the user takes longer than 60 seconds to response.

You can do it using a jQuery UI dialog.

```
$(function() {
    resetTimer();
    document.onkeypress = resetTimer;
    document.onmouseover = resetTimer;

    function logout() {
        var t1 = setTimeout(reallyLogout, 60000);
        $("<div>You will be logged out after 60 seconds</div>").dialog({
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                OK: reallyLogout,
                Cancel: function() {
                    clearTimeout(t1);
                    resetTimer();
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    }
    var t;
    function resetTimer() {
        clearTimeout(t);
        t = setTimeout(logout, 10 * 60000); // Logout in 10 minutes
    }

    function reallyLogout() {
        location.href = '../login/login.aspx';
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/47anv8bj/3/)

In the demo I've changed the logout timer to 20 seconds, and the confirmation timeout to 10 seconds, so you can test it in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: Thankyou barmar... can u please provide me  the link of jquery ui

Comment: The website is jqueryui.com. Is google not working for you?

Comment: i m using this one http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js

Comment: I thought you wanted a link to the documentation, not the script.

Comment: I don't know why it's not working for you, it works for me. Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: no error is thrown... the main issue is popup is not displayed. i think http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js is not correct  jquery for it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88082/discussion-between-user2179026-and-barmar).

Comment: That's the same version of jQuery UI that I'm using in my fiddle.

Comment: does the popup form has any css